# Why does kurtosis of residuals vs. standardized residuals differ in GARCH models?

Tags: r, residuals, garch, kurtosis

So I have used GARCH modelling and obtained both residuals and standardized residuals from that model but kurtosis of both of this series should be same?  I am using `rugarch` package of R. Any help is appreciated.

```
spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH",  garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
               mean.model     = list(armaOrder = c(0,1 )))

garch1 <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = train_ret)

rest<-residuals(garch1,standardize=FALSE)

standresid <- residuals(garch1,standardize=TRUE)
> kurtosis(rest)
[1] 5.255879
> kurtosis(standresid)
[1] 1.904553
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a GARCH model, standardized residuals and raw residuals are not the same. Consider a GARCH(1,1) model for a time series $x_t$ with conditional mean $\mu_t$ and conditional variance $\sigma_t^2$:

\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \mu_t+u_t, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + \alpha_1 u_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.d.(0,1).
\end{aligned}

Raw residuals are empirical counterparts (estimates) of $u_t$ while standardized residuals are empirical counterparts of $\varepsilon_t$. You would expect the kurtosis of raw residuals to be higher than that of standardized residuals. This is why in GARCH models, standardized innovations (theoretical counterparts of standardized residuals) may be assumed to be normal even though raw innovations are heavy-tailed. When a heavy-tailed distribution is assumed for standardized innovations, the implied distribution of raw innovations has even heavier tails.

Comment: So actually I am employing Extreme Value Theory on the residuals. Which should be on standardized residuals εt. So if I have done on `standresid <- residuals(garch1,standardize=TRUE)`   that should be correct?

Comment: @Danish, I suppose, yes. If you are sure you should be employing EVT on standardized residuals.

Comment: @RichardHardy Is there a test or heuristic to confirm that one has the correct amount of kurtosis assumed for one's theoretical/standardized innovations? If I understand you correctly, raw innovations will *always* have heavier tails.

Comment: @ArashHowaida, I would first look at whether the model passes diagnostic tests and/or if it forecasts well. Kurtosis per se need not be that important, in my opinion.